# NullPointerException happening intermittently with Hibernate criteriaQuery

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, entitymanager, hikaricp

I am working on a springboot application in a multi-threading environment where I am using Hibernate with **javax.persistence.EntityManager** to access database. I have separate HikariPools for read and write queries.

Here, the multiple threads while doing read operation from database (all the read queries) are using a single read connection (since I have autowired the entityManager and not using PersistanceContext). And similarly multiple threads will write to db as well with the help of writeEntityManager where a single connection is being used by all of the threads.

I am facing an issue with **AbstractLockUpgradeEventListener.upgradeLock** . This is happening intermittently and could not find the exact root cause for this.

Few assumptions:-

- DB utilization touches 100%.( That might give an edge to this issue)
- Lock is applied before executing any write query and threads are getting starved if one thread takes more than enough time

[image: Attached the screenshot of the complete exception trace.]

Can anyone suggest something here w.r.t design or implementation strategy or on what could be the actual root cause.

This only happens once in a while

Comment: Looks like you are passing a null lock hint somehow, but without seeing the code, it's hard to say how this can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hibernate EntityManager is not thread-safe, you must not use it from multiple threads.

In fact the EntityManager AND the objects loaded must not be used from multiple threads

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-and-multithreading/289